# How to convert const Countries List with code defined?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

In vuejs2 app I have list of countries in format

```
export const settingsCountriesList = {
    "AF": "Afghanistan",
    "AL": "Albania",
```

and I need to convert it to format  {code:'', label:''} for using in

```
let retArray= []
this.convertObjectToArray(this.countriesList).map((next_country, index, next_country_key) => {
    console.log('next_country::')
    console.log(next_country)
    console.log('index::')
    console.log(index)

    console.log('next_country_key::')
    console.log(next_country_key)


    retArray.push({code:next_country_key, label:next_country_key})
})
```

and the code above does not work, as I get valid next_country and index, but not next_country_key.
Which is valid way to get country key for any item ?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```js
const settingsCountriesList = {
  "AF": "Afghanistan",
  "AL": "Albania",
}

const countriesList = Object.entries(settingsCountriesList).map(([code, label]) => ({
  code,
  label
}))

console.log(countriesList)
```

For further reading: [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/object/entries), [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment),